# Fourier Ideal Lowpass filter result is bit weird

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, fft, lowpass-filter

I'm trying to implement a Fourier ideal lowpass filter. The result I got is kind of correct (I guess?), but there are some weird unprocessed pixels around the image.

50 is the cutoff radius.

Here is the picture of original image, grayscale, Fourier transform + filtered, and reverse transform back to original image.

[image: result]

Here is my code:

```
function idealLowHighPass(img,par,d0){
  let height=img.rows;
  let width=img.cols;
  let prettypls=img.clone();
  let temp=createArray(height,width);
  let tmp = fastFourier(img);
  var tempD;

  let fraction = 0.3;
  let filter = 1;
  var x = width/2;
  var y = height/2;
  var state = -1;
  for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){

      if(i > y && j > x){
        state = 3;
      }
      else if( i > y){
        state = 1;
      }
      else if (j > x){
        state = 2;
      }
      else{
        state = 0;
      }

      switch(state){
        case 0:
            tempD = (i * i + j * j);
            tempD = Math.sqrt(tempD);
            break;
        case 1:
            tempD = ((height - i) * (height - i) + j * j);
            tempD = Math.sqrt(tempD);
            break;
        case 2:
            tempD = (i * i + (width - j) * (width - j));
            tempD = Math.sqrt(tempD);
            break;
        case 3:
            tempD = ((height - i) * (height - i) + (width - j) * (width - j));
            tempD = Math.sqrt(tempD);
            break;
        default:
            break;
      }

      if(par == 'ideallowpass'){

        if(tempD <= d0){
            tempD = 1;
        }
        else{
            tempD = 0;
        }
      }
      tmp[i][j].re*=tempD;
      tmp[i][j].im*=tempD; 
    }
  }

  //HANDLE FFT
  //take the magnitudes
  for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
      temp[i][j]=Math.round(tmp[i][j].re);
    }
  }

  temp=logTransform(temp,height,width);
  for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
      let pixel = prettypls.ucharPtr(i,j);
      pixel[0]=Math.round(temp[i][j]);
    }
  }

  // rearrange the quadrants of Fourier image
  // so that the origin is at the image center
  let cx = prettypls.cols / 2;
  let cy = prettypls.rows / 2;
  let tmp2 = new cv.Mat();

  let rect0 = new cv.Rect(0, 0, cx, cy);
  let rect1 = new cv.Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy);
  let rect2 = new cv.Rect(0, cy, cx, cy);
  let rect3 = new cv.Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy);

  let q0 = prettypls.roi(rect0);
  let q1 = prettypls.roi(rect1);
  let q2 = prettypls.roi(rect2);
  let q3 = prettypls.roi(rect3);

  // exchange 1 and 4 quadrants
  q0.copyTo(tmp2);
  q3.copyTo(q0);
  tmp2.copyTo(q3);

  // exchange 2 and 3 quadrants
  q1.copyTo(tmp2);
  q2.copyTo(q1);
  tmp2.copyTo(q2);

  cv.imshow('fourierTransform', prettypls);

  //HANDLE IFFT
  let tmp1 = reverseFastFourier(tmp,height,width);
  //take the magnitudes
  for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
      temp[i][j]=Math.round(tmp1[i][j].re);
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
      let pixel = prettypls.ucharPtr(i,j);
      pixel[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, temp[i][j]));
    }
  }
  cv.imshow('reverseFourier', prettypls);
  temp=[];tmp=[];prettypls.delete();
}
```

Is there something I missed or something wrong with my code?

Comment: Is that log transform and magnitude computation part of the computation of the filtered image or just for intermediate display? Again, I have a hard time following the code with `temp`, `tmp`, `tmp1`, etc. Please remove the bits that are not relevant to the computation of the final filtered image. It will make it a lot easier for you to get an answer.

Comment: @CrisLuengo done mate , thanks for your advice !

Comment: @CrisLuengo just edited. its just part of the display. so basically i calculate the distance (tempD) based on each quadrant (state) , then show the fourier and inverse it back

Comment: imho the black spots in the white area look like  some byte-overflow (values which would be bigger than 255 but are limited to 8 bit)

Comment: I've added the JavaScript tag because it is important to tag with the language you are using. Please fix if I guessed wrong at the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is in this line:

```
pixel[0]=Math.round(temp[i][j]);
```

Here you copy a floating-point value, resulting from the real component of the inverse Fourier transform, into an unsigned 8-bit integer (I presume from what I can see in the code).

If one of these values is slightly above 255, which can happen with an "ideal" low-pass filter because of the ringing artefacts, then the conversion to 8-bit unsigned integer will cause the value to wrap around.

What you need to do is clamp the value to the [0,255] range. Replace that line with:

```
pixel[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, temp[i][j]));
```

Note: I'm guessing that this syntax will work based on some quick Googling, but it is the *concept* that you need to look at...

The `Math.round` call is not necessary, as `temp` already contains rounded values.

Comment: you read that correct , i copy a floating point from real ift. and your syntax works fine too , unfortunately it's doesnt solve the problem as the result remains the same. anyway thanks for your help , really appreciate it !

Comment: @WellyWinata: Did you put this in the last section of code, where you create the image for `reverseFourier`? You have some repeated bits of code, and I notice now that this particular line of code happens twice in your program. I used the word "guess" in my answer, but I am actually very certain that this is your problem, and you need to make sure the cast from float to 8-bit int goes correctly. How to do so in JavaScript I'm less certain of.

Comment: just edited the code , please take a look. thats what you meant right ?

Comment: @WellyWinata: as long as `temp` is a floating-point array, and not a uint8 array. I can't tell because I don't know JavaScript. Why do you have so many arrays with such similar names? And why don't you combine those two double loops into one? You don't need `temp` there at all!

Comment: It worked like charm , ive been trying to figure that out for days. thanks mate , really appreciate it !